# Trying to make a strip plot in R where each row is color by identity and points changes transparency based on another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a strip plot where each row is colored by the variable "ident" and then the points change transparency based on variable "Pvalue" however I want to have a threshold where only points with pvalue <0.1 are colored the rest should be a light grey color.

So far I tried the following:

```
p = ggplot(da_results, aes(x=ident, y=logFC,color = ident)) +
geom_jitter()+coord_flip()+geom_point(alpha = da_results$PValue) + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

which gives me everything except for the pvalue thresholds.